# Mysql Insert taking too long. Table need optimzation

Tags: mysql, php, mysqli

I have around 60 tables and a video table with over 600,000 rows. with 4 Btree and 2 FULLText Indexes and have around 30 Columns.

Server Specs are high, over 30G of Ram, Intel Xeon Processor.

Mysql configs are here

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = 10.0.0.128
tmpdir=/var/tmp/mysql
innodb_file_per_table=1
local-infile=0
max_connections = 8192
max_user_connections = 8192
key_buffer_size = 256M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
join_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 2M
sort_buffer_size = 2M
table_cache = 16384
thread_cache_size = 384
wait_timeout = 15
connect_timeout = 15
tmp_table_size = 1024M
max_heap_table_size = 1024M
max_allowed_packet = 64M
net_buffer_length = 16384
max_connect_errors = 1000
thread_concurrency = 32
concurrent_insert = 2
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 8M
query_cache_limit = 64M
query_cache_size = 1024M
query_cache_type = 1
query_prealloc_size = 262144
query_alloc_block_size = 65536
transaction_alloc_block_size = 8192
transaction_prealloc_size = 4096
max_write_lock_count = 16
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_thread_concurrency=16
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT

slow_query_log=0
long_query_time=5
slow_query_log_file=/var/lib/mysql/slow.log

log-bin=mysql-bin
server-id=1

expire_logs_days = 7
max_binlog_size = 512M

[mysqld_safe]
open_files_limit = 58192

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 384M
sort_buffer = 384M
read_buffer = 256M
write_buffer = 256M
```

This query

```
INSERT into video (file,userid) VALUES (11223,1);
```

is taking around ~4 minutes .

```
INSER into users (username,email) VALUES ('test','test@test.tld');
```

Takes 0.00s

I seriusly need some expert advice on Table optimzation. Things I have done wrong from start

- Didn't plan the table properly
- Added few indexes after 200,000 rows crossed.

Whats the best solution?

Comment: I have increased the "key_buffer_size" to "5G" , looks like problem is solved but lets keep this discussion open to see if there are other possible solutions available.

Comment: Can you clarify if the insert that took 4 minutes was literally just a single insert or representative of hundreds of thousands?  Is each insert a single row or are you writing multiple rows foreach "INSERT" query?

Comment: Yes, that was the single insert which took 4 minutes But as it was a production server, atleast 10 inserts/writes are made per second.

Comment: I have changed the engine to InnoDB, before it was MyIsam, removed FULLTEXT indexes as they are not required. Removed all unused Columns (normalized) ...lets see if this brings performance.

Comment: Is this delay reproducible? 4 minutes is plenty of time to capture a process list and show engine innodb status;  Maybe you could capture those and update with a link to a pastebin dump of the contents?

Comment: After changing engine to InnoDB, CHanging Mysql Settings, set innodb_buffer_pool_size to 15G. Its working absolutely fine. 

MyIsam may have some limitations but I would say structuring each and every field matters.

I had 4 Fields with MediumText, not needed, Text fields trimmed to Varchar where I can, changed INT lengths to the exact requirements. and the Re-indexed and Optimzed the table.

Insert time is back to 0.00s